# How can I extract features from audio to dataset?

Tags: python, audio, feature-extraction, datadirectory

I have a folder stored on the my desktop, and its contains 187 audio file in WAV format.  I want to extract features from audio files and I executed the following code for extract features audio and to save the features in CSV file, but I obtained excel file with no value, its include only the title for each column and  the output for len(audio-files) was 0..but its must be 187. How can I solve this problem???

```
  from glob import glob
    data_dir = './audio featur-extraction\audio-setA/'
    audio_files = glob(data_dir + '*.wav')
    len(audio_files)
        
       
    from librosa import feature
    import numpy as np
    
    fn_list_i = [
        feature.chroma_stft,
        feature.spectral_centroid,
        feature.spectral_bandwidth,
        feature.spectral_rolloff,
      
    ]
      
    fn_list_ii = [
        
      
        
        feature.zero_crossing_rate
            
    ]
      
    
    def get_feature_vector(y,sr):  
      feat_vect_i = [ np.mean(funct(y,sr)) for funct in fn_list_i]
      feat_vect_ii = [ np.mean(funct(y)) for funct in fn_list_ii]
      
      feature_vector =   feat_vect_i + feat_vect_ii  
      return feature_vector
    
    #build the matrix with normal audios featurized
    audios_feat = []
    for file in audio_files:
      '''
      y is the time series array of the audio file, a 1D np.ndarray
      sr is the sampling rate, a number
      '''  
      y,sr = librosa.load(file,sr=None)   
      feature_vector = get_feature_vector(y, sr) 
      audios_feat.append(feature_vector)  
      print('.', end= " ")
      
      print(audios_feat)
      #.........................
    import csv
    
    norm_output = 'normals_00.csv'
    
    
    header =[
        'chroma_stft',
        'spectral_centroid',
        'spectral_bandwidth',
        'spectral_rolloff',
        'zero_crossing_rate',
        
    ]
    
    #WARNING : this overwrites the file each time. Be aware of this because feature extraction step takes time.
    with open(norm_output,'+w') as f:
      csv_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
      csv_writer.writerow(header)
      csv_writer.writerows(audios_feat)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 audio_files = glob(data_dir + '/*.wav')
```

it solved by add slash before the star symbole

Answer (score 2):

The error is in this line:

```
data_dir = './audio featur-extraction\audio-setA/'
```

It's the extra slash. Replace it with backslash (as in rest of the path) and you will be good to go. In future: debug your code. Step line by line through the code and find the error. If length of the array with paths to process is zero, nothing will be computed.

It should be

```
data_dir = r'audio featur-extraction\audio-setA\' # for Windows
```

*or*

```
data_dir = 'audio featur-extraction/audio-setA/' # for Mac / Linux.
```

More generally, use os.path.joinin your code

Comment: dear @Lukasz Tracewski, I replace it with backslash as in the following code: data_dir = '.\audio featur-extraction\audio-setA' , but the excel file still doesn't contain values, and not appear any error code after execution the codes.

Comment: @Merna It should be `data_dir = 'audio featur-extraction\audio-setA\' for Windows or `data_dir = 'audio featur-extraction/audio-setA/' for Mac / Linux. More generally, use `os.path.join`in your code.

Comment: I use windows system, and I  replace  my code with :  data_dir = 'audio featur-extraction\audio-setA\'   then I get this error :  path = 'audio featur-extraction\audio-setA\'
                                                ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal @Lukasz Tracewski

Comment: @Merna Use raw string like this `r 'audio featur-extraction\audio-setA\'` or double backslash ` 'audio featur-extraction\\audio-setA\\'`. Backslash is a special character in Python.

Comment: I found the error is in the following line:  audio_files = glob(data_dir + '*.wav')         it solved by add slash before the star symbol. @ Lukasz Tracewski

Comment: @Merna If you look at my answer, it also had that slash. You essentially took what I wrote and pasted as your answer. It's hardly useful and not how this community works.